# What windows user does glassfish 3.1 runs as?

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I'm trying to execute this from a webservice running on netbeans 7.2 prepackaged glassfish:

```
void correrMotor() throws InterruptedException {

    try {
//          Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
//          Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\UNIBE\\Inv Ops\\Mercalum\\correrMotor.bat");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\UNIBE\\Inv Ops\\Mercalum\\correrMotor.bat");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(line); 
    }} 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EjecutarMotor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But all I get is an error that the .exe (my correrMotor.bat is tying to call an executable) can't be found, but if I run the bat using windows explorer, it runs without problem, I suspect it's because of permission, Can anybody help me on this?